# "Field x is never used" not found from Intellij's Setting/Inspection/Java list, how to get an highlight instead of an onmouseover warning?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I could not find "Field x is never used" in Intellij's

> Setting/Inspection/Java

list.

How to get a systematic highlight instead of an "on mouse-over" warning in the case of unused member fields ?

By the way, the command "Show Inspection Description" available top-right of the popup is greyed-out.

[image: Show Inspection Description greyed out]

I also set Java's "Unused declaration" inspection to the "Error" then "Severe" status, the location is in thos case indicated by a corresponding color bar on the right slider, but nothing do change in the editor … incidentally, the colored bar appear for unassigned members and this is what I do not want since it happen for autowired Spring members and this is not an error ..I would need a warning in the editor just for
unused members ..

Comment: The inspection you are searching for is named `Unused declaration`. Please check if it is set to `Warning` (the default setting)

Comment: Thank you very much @FlatEric, I set Java's "Unused declaration" inspection to the "Error" then "Severe" status, the location is now indicated by a corresponding color bar on the right slider, but nothing do change in the editor … incidentally, the colored bar appear for unassigned members and this is what I do not want since it happen for autowired Spring members..

Comment: for autowired you should press alt + enter then select `suppress unused warning is annotated with foo.bar.autowired`

Answer (score 1):

The intention shouldn't be grayed out, that looks like a bug - since @olga already mentioned. But that doesn't hinder you from achieving what you want

So, in order to find that intention. Go to the unsed variable and hit `ALT` + `Enter`:

[image]

Use the right arror key ->
[image]

Hit enter and you will be routed to the appropriate inspection setting:

Then change from `warning` to `error`:
[image]

From now on every unused variable will be marked as an error instead of warning.

**Change The Appearence**

If you don't want to have an error mark and you just want to change how the warinig is displayed, do the following:

Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Color Scheme` -> `General`
then select `Errors and Warnings` and `Unused symbol`.
You can customize the apperance on the right side.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the issue already created for Editor highlighting problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242284
and the issue for the "Show inspection description": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252200